# Ran 0 tests in 0.000s even when I have the file tests.py on windows 10

Tags: python, django

I have my app installed

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  "table_booker.apps.TableBookerConfig",
  "django_nose",
]
```

My tests.py file I have

```
from django.test import TestCase

class AnimalTests(TestCase):
    def test_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, False)
```

When I try to run my tests with

```
python manage.py test
```

I get Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3n87.png)

Comment: Show your file tree. Where exactly do you have the file `tests.py`?

Comment: My tests.py files are located in my app. So on vs code I click on my app folder and tests.py shows up underneath